# How to implement line-through using css to custom checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

```
    ---------------------------------HTML code----------------------------------------  
       <label class="round">
            <input type="checkbox" id="round-checkbox" class="check-btn">
            <span></span>
        </label>
            <label for="round-checkbox" id="task-text" >Hello Smple TEXT</label>
```

-----------------------------------------CSS code-----------------------------------------------

```
  .round input:checked+label{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

I tried the above approach but it is not working...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should read what the `label` tag is used for (why do you have 2 labels for the same field?).

Then, with a "cleaner" HTML, it becomes easier:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="box" class="box">
  <span class="label-text">label text</span>
</label>

.box {
  display: none;
}

.box:checked ~ .label-text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Now you got the idea, you can adapt to "custom" checkbox:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="box" class="box">
  <span class="custom-box"></span>
  <span class="label-text">label text</span>
</label>

.box {
  display: none;
}

.custom-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: green;
}

.box:checked ~ .custom-box {
  background: red;
}

.box:checked ~ .label-text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```